# How can I determine why all the faucets are giving only warm water when turned to cold?

Tags: plumbing, washer

When ever we turn on the cold faucet in any room in out house we only get luke warm water. I have heard that a faulty washing machine inlet valve can cause this. are there any ways to test that theory? Also any other suggestions to check? We do live in phx, but we should still be able to get semi cold water. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Check the temperature of the main home water supply pipe, and compare it to other pipes in the house. Nothing else will be colder, but the other cold water pipes shouldn't be much warmer.

If you find a presumed cold water pipe that's significantly warmer than the main supply, then you can search for the source of the heat. If, for instance, the washing machine is bridging its cold and hot source, then perhaps your cold water faucets are pulling some hot water through the washing machine.

Comment: Will do, but I know the main supply will be hot as it is exposed outside and its about 110 degrees outside almost every day.

Comment: Well, then perhaps that's your answer. If the water coming into the house is warm, nothing inside is going to make it any cooler.

Comment: True, but we ran the water for about 10 minutes through all taps and it never cooled off at all. It seems that it should have at least dropped temp a little at some point once all the water was cleared from the lines and new water was coming in.

Comment: Then, after those ten minutes, do what I suggested above: check the main supply temp, and then the various branches, to see if you can find a source for the surprising warmth (beyond your 110 degree weather).